# Plotting individual colormap row with distinct colorbar and visualizing them

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap

I am trying to create colorbar from matplotlib for each data row i.e. each datarow heatmap is defined by its individual colormap. The sample is as shown in this picture.

[image]

I tried to solve this problem by merging colormaps, but I can only merge the different colorbars into one.

I did googling for this kind of problem as well as read the documentation from matplotlib but could not find any reliable document for this kind of problem. Is there any procedure to solve this kind of problem. I am currently stuck in the middle of nowhere by this problem.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Maybe you want to use the same vmin and vmax for each row? [Colormap Normalization](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html)

Comment: @JohanC vmax, vmin is same but mid-point for each colorbar is different as well as density of green gradient which will be calculated seperately.